# Is there a better way to map menu click events to it's corresponding code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, basically when I click a menu option a corresponding html is loaded into the *content block* of the layout page after executing some other set of codes, Now I have mapped each menu options' click event to it's corresponding set of codes to execute as follows;

```
 <li onclick="changeContentTo('home');">About Us</li>
 <li onclick="changeContentTo('rules');">Rules</li>
```

The mapping is done using switch case

```
    case "rules":
         /* something here */
         $c.load("actsAndRules.htm" ) ;
         break;
    case "home":
         /* something else here*/
         $c.load("content.htm" ) ;       
         break;
```

I was wondering is there any better/proper method to do this?

**I don't want to bind click event to a selector say `$('.myLink').click()` for example and no HTML5 coding, event handling will be the same as above**

Basically what I want is to strip that mapping as much as possible out of the code and place it in a seperate obj ( which maybe resides in a seperate JS file ) something that will imitate a table/reference for mapping i.e. if I were to change a mapping I will only have to update that make-believe table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a dictionary?

```
var $map = {'rules': 'actsAndRules.html', 'home': 'content.html'};
```

Now, instead of switch you can directly

```
$c.load($map[$arg]);
```

Assuming `$arg` is your function argument name.

**EDIT**

To run code only if any of the switch cases were satisfied, you can do something like this:

```
var $flag = false;
// your switch
...
case default:
    $flag = true;
    break;
...

// after switch
if (!$flag) {
// common code.
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I want, I also wanted to spare myself from mentioning 'rules', 'home'.. etc..etc...while calling the function now as I have mentioned in my question I don't want to bind events, so If you can think of some work around for that that will be helpful

Comment: hmmm I don't need numbers, instead I will assign an id to the `li`and will fetch that no problem, but tell me where am I gonna write the extra codes like I have written in the switch cases ?? I still have to use that logic don't I?

Comment: If you are still patient enough with me, I was wondering if there is anyway I can avoid writing the common code `$c.load(map[option] );` It shouldn't be before or after the switch case, and it shouldn't execute if `default` condition occurs, any thoughts on that?

Comment: can you remove the first _edit_ and I will mark this as the answer

Comment: I am also using fall-through switch case for common codes(with no other extra codes) .

Comment: as a side note: the `$` prefix for variable names seems to come from `PHP` background here. in `javascript`, it is typically used for variables containing `jQuery` elements. So I guess the `$c` is okay, as that seems to be a `jQuery element`, but `$map` and `$flag` is not preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

**HTML**

```
<li onclick="changeContentTo('home','content.htm');">About Us</li>
<li onclick="changeContentTo('rules','actsAndRules.htm');">Rules</li>

<script>
  function changeContentTo(type,page){
    $elesToHide=something;// let $elesToHide and $c are pre defined
    if(!$elesToHide.is(":visible"))
         $elesToHide.slideDown()
    $c.load(page) ;    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to reduce the code in both html and JS files, I want to strip that mapping as much as possible out of these two and place it in a seperate obj / JS file itsef something that will imitate a table/reference

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<li class="nav-item" data-location="content.htm">About Us</li>
<li class="nav-item" data-location="actsAndRules.htm">Rules</li>
```

Then

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav-item').click(function(){
        if(!$elesToHide.is(":visible")){
            $elesToHide.slideDown();
        }
        $c.load($this.data('location') ) ;
    })
})
```

Comment: Beat me by a second! :)

Comment: Take a look at my updated question please, no HTML5 no general selector, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="l1" class="menuItem" data-item="home.htm" ></li>
<li id="l2" class="menuItem" data-item="actsAndRules.htm" ></li>
<li id="l3" class="menuItem" data-item="content.htm" ></li>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuItem').click(function(e){
        $c.load($(this).attr('data-item'));
    });
});
```

Edit:

The HTML5 "data-" attribute will not be a problem even if you are not using HTML5. In ASP.Net the attributes are passed as-is to the client. Just leave the value blank where you don't need processing.

If you don't want to bind click on `li`, then you can bind it on the parent using event-delegation:

```
<ul id="list">
<li.....
<li.....
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list').click(function(e){
        var $elem = $(e.target);
        var content = $elem.attr('data-item');
        if ($.trim(content)) {
            $c.load(content);
        }
    });
});
```

Binding `click` to a selector is preferable over specifying `onclick` inline with each element.

You can easily wrap that snippet into a function and store it separately in external js file to be called from here.

Comment: Take a look at my updated question please, no HTML5 & no general selector, Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the edit too, but please no binding of events (I am not stubborn, I just want an onclick to be visible on that html tag for my own reason) and no `data-` attributes too, the `attr()` may pickup on it, but If I am not using HTML5 then I don't want to mislead anyone thinking that I do with just one look at that and basically what I want is somewhat similar to @Prasanth's answer, I am not worried about event handling but rather the mapping

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$elesToHide.is(":visible"))
            $elesToHide.slideDown();
```

this part seems to always be the same.
Just put it before your `switch` part.

Then, it only boils down to distinguish the url. You could just pass that directly:

```
<li onclick="changeContentTo('content.htm');">About Us</li>
 <li onclick="changeContentTo('actsAndRules.htm');">Rules</li>



$c.load(parameterOfFunction ) ;
```

Comment: the part `if(!$elesToHide.is(":visible"))$elesToHide.slideDown();` changes, I have posted only a sample there, I also execute other set of codes other that toggling visibility!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li clickable load-link="content.htm">About Us</li>
<li clickable load-link="actsAndRules.htm">Rules</li>

$(function(){
 $('clickable').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $c.load($this.data('location') ) ;
 });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at my updated question please, no HTML5 & no general selector, Thanks